# Google Maps numbered markers all displaying same number

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm building a map where I have to have numbered markers, along with a list underneath where the markers match what's displayed on the map. I'm loading the array of addresses and populating my list from the same array. The marker positions are showing up correctly on the map and the list is correct, but the numbers on the markers are all the same (they end up being the number of markers on the map + 1). So in this example, since there are 3 addresses each marker displays "4".

My code:

```
function initialize()
{

var map;
var elevator;
var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0708,-118.2762),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
map = new google.maps.Map($('#googleMap')[0], myOptions);

var addresses = [
{NAME:"an address name string",ADDRESS:"an address number string"},
{NAME:"an address name string",ADDRESS:"an address number string"},
{NAME:"an address name string",ADDRESS:"an address number string"}
]

for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

    //The list, which works correctly
    $("#listID").append("<li><img src='http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker" + (x + 1) + ".png' alt='marker'><strong>" + addresses[x].NAME + "</strong><br>" + addresses[x].ADDRESS + "<br></li>");

    //Based off another SO answer, to populate the map based on addresses without having to look up lat/lng
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x].ADDRESS +'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var image = 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker' + (x + 1) + '.png';
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            icon: image,
            map: map
        });

    });
}

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use function closure to associate the number with the request:

```
function geocodeAddress(x, map) {
    //populate the map based on addresses using the geocoder to look up lat/lng
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x].ADDRESS +'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var image = 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker' + (x + 1) + '.png';
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            icon: image,
            map: map
        });

    });
}
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/o5v43rby/1/)

```js
function initialize() {
  function geocodeAddress(x, map) {
    //Based off another SO answer, to populate the map based on addresses without having to look up lat/lng
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + addresses[x].ADDRESS + '&sensor=false', null, function(data) {
      var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
      var image = 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker' + (x + 1) + '.png';
      new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        icon: image,
        map: map
      });

    });
  }


  var map;
  var elevator;
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 9,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0708, -118.2762),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map($('#googleMap')[0], myOptions);

  var addresses = [{
    NAME: "an address name string 1",
    ADDRESS: "Los Angeles, CA"
  }, {
    NAME: "an address name string 2",
    ADDRESS: "Long Beach, CA"
  }, {
    NAME: "an address name string 3",
    ADDRESS: "Anaheim, CA"
  }]

  for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {

    //The list, which works correctly
    $("#listID").append("<li><img src='http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker" + (x + 1) + ".png' alt='marker'><strong>" + addresses[x].NAME + "</strong><br>" + addresses[x].ADDRESS + "<br></li>");
    geocodeAddress(x, map);

  }
}




google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#googleMap {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="googleMap" style="border: 2px solid #3872ac;"></div>
<div id="listID"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for example. jQuery allowed thread forloop

```
for (var x = 0; x < addresses.length; x++) {
  (function(x){
    //The list, which works correctly
    $("#listID").append("<li><img src='http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker" + (x + 1) + ".png' alt='marker'><strong>" + addresses[x].NAME + "</strong><br>" + addresses[x].ADDRESS + "<br></li>");

    //Based off another SO answer, to populate the map based on addresses without having to look up lat/lng
    $.getJSON('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+addresses[x].ADDRESS +'&sensor=false', null, function (data) {
        var p = data.results[0].geometry.location;
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(p.lat, p.lng);
        var image = 'http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markers/blue/marker' + (x + 1) + '.png';
        new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            icon: image,
            map: map
        });

    });
    })(x);
}
```